# How to access nested elements

Tags: javascript, json, object, electron

So I have some items that are nested something like this.

```
grindstone:{
  1:{
   range: {
    0: {min: 80 , max: 120}, 
    1: {min: 100, max: 200}, 
    2: {min: 180, max: 250}, 
    3: {min: 230, max: 450}, 
    4: {min: 430, max: 550}
  }
},
```

...

Later, in the same file, I call that, and it looks something like:

```
grindVals(craft_id) {
var map = {};
var grind = this.rune;
var typeNumber = Number(craft_id.toString().slice(-4, -2))
if(typeNumber < 10){
  typeNumber = Number (typeNumber.toString().slice(1));
}
map.set =  grind.sets[Number(craft_id.toString().slice(0, -4))];
map.grade = grind.quality[Number(craft_id.toString().slice(-1))];
map.type = grind.effectTypes [typeNumber];
console.log("this.grindstone[" + typeNumber + "][" + Number(craft_id.toString().slice(-1))+ "].min");

--->Error Happens here
map.min = this.grindstone[typeNumber][Number(craft_id.toString().slice(-1))].min;
map.max = this.grindstone[typeNumber][Number(craft_id.toString().slice(-1))].max;
return map;
},
```

The output is something like:

this.grindstone[1][2].min

Which is returning an error along the lines of Cannot find item [2] of undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You only have one item in your main object, and that item has only one item. The good thing is, you can access the child item by index name. this.grindstone[1][range][x]

Comment: @Joraid, `range` has, in your case, to be `range = 'range'`. otherwise it does not work.

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah absolutely correct, it's a string, not a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `range` property inbetween (dot notation):

```
this.grindstone[typeNumber].range[Number(craft_id.toString().slice(-1))].min
//                         ^^^^^^
```

or (bracket notation)

```
this.grindstone[typeNumber]['range'][Number(craft_id.toString().slice(-1))].min
//                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

read more here about [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) or [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: I'm in the process of testing this out -- in the interim, do you have a good resource of where I can read up a bit on data access in javascript?  I'm working in an open source app written in electron and it's not fully sensical to me coming over from Java.

Comment: you could have a look to the two links above. a good idea is to use an ide, like ms visual studio and on doubt, always when getting *can not access undefined*, then you have something wron with the access to the properties. in this case, you could make anoutput of the structure just one property before the actual (missing) property.

Comment: I'm using VS code at the moment, but it doesn't seem to be giving me much until the code is executed, at which time it does throw an exception, is there some addon that will do some linting for me?

Comment: you could use the community edition of vs. actually i don't use vs code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was doing something stupid and you helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to access the `range` property:

```
this.grindstone[1].range[2]
```

Or you can use arrays in the `grindstone` object:

```
var grindstone = {
    1 : [
        {min: 80 , max: 120},
        {min: 100, max: 200},
        {min: 180, max: 250},
        {min: 230, max: 450},
        {min: 430, max: 550}
    ]
}
```

If you use this second approach, you can write:

```
this.grindstone[1][2]
```